# QML ListView gets stuck when flicking

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ListView in my qml file, but when I am overscrolling it, it gets stuck for a several seconds and then flicks back. Does anyone know what can be the reason of that delay before flicking back?

Also, it's only freezes, when the text inside my delegates is on Russian language. On english it works fine
[image]

Upd:
There is nothing specific, but minimal, reproducible example:

```
ListView {
        id: list
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            top: parent.top
        }
        height: parent.height
        width: 502
        interactive: height < contentHeight
        spacing: 24
        currentIndex: -1

        footer: Item {
            height: 100
        }

        delegate: Item {
            anchors {
                left: list.contentItem.left
                right: list.contentItem.right
                leftMargin: 40
                rightMargin: 40
            }
            implicitHeight: Math.max(image.height, description.implicitHeight)
        // Some other code
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: OknaGui.ScrollBar { id: scrollBar } // Just a scrollbar
    }
```

Comment: A minimal, reproducible example would be helpful here.

Comment: It's just an ordinary ListView. If it will be helpful to you, I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the proper solution, but you can disable overscroll at all with `boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds`

Comment: Yeah, I've solved this issue like that. But it would be cool to save previous functionality